# Biztalk Server 2010 - Functoid output is incorrectly encoded in target document

Tags: encoding, mapping, biztalk

I have stumbled onto a problem that has me completely stumped.

Scenario:

1) I have an input XML message with encoding iso-8859-1 that contains Swedish characters.

2) I have a mapping WITHOUT any XSLT Encoding set

3) The mapping sets one of the target fields statically through a mapping functoid. The value contains Swedish characters.

4) I have an output XML message that gets the encoding iso-8859-1 set through a custom pipeline (as per instructions here: http://blog.vertica.dk/2013/09/16/how-to-encode-xml-sent-from-biztalk/)

5) All messages have had their encodings confirmed both by eye and through byte analysis of characters. They are in fact iso-8859-1.

Problem:

If the Swedish characters are present in the source document and mapped to a target field, the target field is correctly encoded. If the Swedish characters come from a functoid in the map, the encoding is faulty and I get gibberish in that field.

I have tried different target encodings (among others Windows-1252, UTF-8), using all sorts of different functoids to set the value. Nothing helps.

To add insult to injury, I've had an associate try out the schemas and mapping on another server, and he does NOT experience this problem.

Any suggestions are most welcome, this is driving me insane!

Oh - I am running on Biztalk Server 2010 3.9.469.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (64-bit).

Best regards,

Goran

Comment: Is the other computer running the same versions and is the Locale the same?

Comment: Yes, same versions. Same Locale.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error with no success.  If no-one else is able to reproduce it there may be something wrong with that BizTalk server, e.g. corrupted/missing code page.